# Centering initial row of sidebar Menu

Tags: html, css

I've used this tutorial http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/07/30/google-nexus-website-menu/ to create a Sidebar in my _Layout code. I'm trying to have the sidebar the li -> a -> "Test Sidebar" element to be on centered. May I ask how do I do that responsively. I can set it with a margin value but that's not very ideal.

_Layout.cshtml code

```
<div class="container">
    <ul id="gn-menu" class="gn-menu-main">
        <li class="gn-trigger">
            <a class="gn-icon gn-icon-menu"><span>Menu</span></a>
            <nav class="gn-menu-wrapper">
                <div class="gn-scroller">
                    <ul class="gn-menu">
                        <li class="gn-search-item">
                            <input placeholder="Search" type="search" class="gn-search">
                            <a class="gn-icon gn-icon-search"><span>Search</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="gn-icon gn-icon-download">Popular</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="gn-icon gn-icon-cog">Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a class="gn-icon gn-icon-help">About us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /gn-scroller -->
            </nav>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://tympanus.net/codrops">Test Sidebar</a></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>

     @RenderBody()
</div><!-- /container -->
<script src="../../Scripts/classie.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/gnmenu.js"></script>
<script>
    new gnMenu(document.getElementById('gn-menu'));
</script>
```

[image]

Codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNjYJd

Comment: take a sceenshot of what you need centered and add it in your Q

Comment: Okay, it has been posted

Comment: can you give the fiddle or codepen?

Comment: @NewbieDeveloper done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some step u need to follow for your solution.

1 - Remove `float:left` from `.gn-menu-main > li` and add to `.gn-menu-main li.gn-trigger`.

2 - Replace `display:block` to `display:inline-block`

3 - Add `text-align:center` and `font-size:0` (font size to set margen) to `.gn-menu-main`

4 - And give font:size according to your design li 13px to `.gn-menu-main > li`

Try by follow these steps may help you here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d6mxLu7q/)

Comment: i just comment out float:right in .gn-menu-main > li:last-child to be center last child if you don't want last child to be center just revert it thanks